# Library for IMAP IDLE

Tags: java, email, imap, hmail-server

I'm looking for a Java library that helps me using IMAP and preferably IDLE.

I need to write a Java application that is notified of and retrieves new email using SSL. The application will check the inbox of an account hosted by hMailServer.

So far I've looked at:

[Apache Commons Imap](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/imap/package-summary.html) but it doesn't seem to implement IDLE.

[JavaPushMail](https://github.com/mofirouz/JavaPushMail) but it is not sufficiently documented (I might be able to work it out but I'm not sure my successors will be as pleased).

[Javamail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), their IMAPFolder seems like a good choice but I'm short on time and writing a stable library for it will take time.

[Chilkatsoft](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-imap.asp) is a $199 library, it's a bit pricy (I know, free and good reliable code is always ease to come by :) Plus, I'm not sure it handles IDLE.

I could go for a solution that polls the inbox if it's documented and stable.

I'd appreciate some example code, a library or a push in the right direction.

Sorry for all the "I" and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and used [Javamail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). Just think it's strange no decent wrapper/client has been written for it yet. Well well, can't have it all. Thanks for the answer, Conor Sherman.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with any of the libraries that you mentioned except Javamail, but I can vouch for it.  I had to write an application that polls an exchange server and parses all the new mail in an inbox.  Here is a snippit of the code used in that project.  I did all the polling in-app, so I wasn't looking into push notifications from server or anything.  I know this isn't precisely what you were asking for, but I hope it is a step in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;


public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Create properties (disable security checks on server)
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try{
            // Get the store
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("servername", "username", "password");

            //connection configuration
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            //get all unread messages in the inbox
            FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false); 
            Message[] messages = folder.search(ft);

            for (int i = messages.length -1; i>=0; i--) {
                messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
            }
            // Close connection 
            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not used it myself, but this library looks good:

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2

> MailCore 2 provide a simple and asynchronous API to work with e-mail protocols IMAP, POP and SMTP. The API has been redesigned from ground up.

Comment: Is that usable from java now?

Comment: @arnt there are Java API docs. Looks like it is possible to call the c++ code via java. I guess it is usable from java. But it is not pure java. I guess you need to compile the core for each platform.